# Programmatically Creating a Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, dynamic-data

I am new to android and I am attempting to programmatically create RelativeLayouts (at least I think that is the only way it will work if my values are dynamic).  Essentially I built a webservice to return a list of values and I want to display those values.  It could be one value or it could be 500.

In my layout.xml I was able to build a RelativeLayout relatively close to what I wanted but I could only populate it once.  Below is my XML:

NoTE: this is the entire XML but he nodes in question are the RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/linear">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/band"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:dropDownSelector="#000000"
        android:textColor="#F0F0F0" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/yearSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#F0F0F0" />

      <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:id="@+id/showRelativeLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="My Application"
            android:id="@+id/thirdLine" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

So I then attempted to build the same in my Activity so that I could iterate through my webservice results.  Below is the method that is called numerous times (for each json array returned).  Unfortunately the behavior is that there will only be one relativeLayout and it is attempting to take up the remainder of the screen (about 90% for the one row).  I am definitely not comprehending something fundamental.

```
private void processRelativeLayout(int count) {
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rl.setLayoutParams(lay);

    //Set the Image
    //TODO:  pull from webservice to get the artist image
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imlay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    imlay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    imlay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    imlay.setMargins(0, 0, 6, 0);

    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    iv.setId(1+count);
    iv.setLayoutParams(imlay);
    rl.addView(iv);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tv1lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 26);
    tv1lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    tv1lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    tv1lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1+count);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setSingleLine();
    tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    tv.setText("Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout");
    tv.setId(2+count);
    tv.setLayoutParams(tv1lay);
    rl.addView(tv);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tv2lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv2lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    tv2lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    tv2lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, 2+count);
    tv2lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,1+count);
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    tv2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    tv2.setText("My Application");
    tv2.setId(count+3);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(tv2lay);
    rl.addView(tv2);

    rootLinear.addView(rl);


    //add the relative layoutll.addView(tv, lay);
}
```

I am also attaching a screenshot of my emulator to show you the output.  I would have expected to see the result 5 times (since I call processRelativeLayout 5 times).

Apologies for the long post but I wanted to give enough information.

Update:  I attempted to post an image but the site says I am not seasoned enough :)

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, the `RelativeLayout` is unable to process the `WRAP_CONTENT` height setting you've attempted to give it, since it has child elements that align to it's bottom. Because of this, it's falling back on matching it's parents height instead, hence why it takes up almost the whole screen. Try either specifying an explicit height in the `rl` layout params, or restructuring it's children to avoid any `ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM` usage - from what I can see, it should be simple enough to set `imlay` to just snap to top (using it's own default height or explicitly specifying one of your own), and have `tv1lay` use the `ALIGN_BOTTOM` rule with the id of `iv`.

Comment: You nailed it!!  That was exactly it.  Removing the WRAP_CONTENT and putting in a value fixed it.  Thank you very much.  Now off to figure out why some of the scrolling isn't working yet.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to be of help - RelativeLayouts have a lot of tricks and subtle requirements that can trip up even the very experienced. Remember to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem :)